# Do ssh_config rules cascade?

Tags: ssh, configuration

I have the following rules

```
Host *
   Compression yes

Host sop
    HostName 192.168.56.101
```

if i `ssh sop` will the compression flag also be added?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, all matching blocks are applied.

If you say `ssh -v sop` it will show you exactly which lines of the config are applied in this case.